# Windows 2012 R2 DNS - BPA warnings

Tags: dns, windows-server-2012-r2

Ok, so I'm running into some DNS issues, and ran the BPA analyzer.

Here is what I see:

```
Warning DNS: Root hint server 128.9.0.107 must respond to NS queries for the    root zone.

Warning DNS: Root hint server 2001:500:2f::f must respond to NS queries for the root zone.  

Warning DNS: Root hint server 198.32.64.12 must respond to NS queries for the root zone.

 Warning    DNS: Root hint server 2001:500:9f::42 must respond to NS queries for the root zone.

 Warning    DNS: Root hint server 2001:500:84::b must respond to NS queries for the root zone.

 Warning    DNS: Root hint server 2001:500:1::53 must respond to NS queries for the root zone.

 Warning    DNS: Root hint server 2001:500:2d::d must respond to NS queries for the root zone.

 Warning    DNS: Root hint server 128.8.10.90 must respond to NS queries for the root zone.

 Warning    DNS: Root hint server 2001:7fe::53 must respond to NS queries for the root zone.

 Warning    DNS: Root hint server 2001:503:ba3e::2:30 must respond to NS queries for the root zone.

 Warning    DNS: Root hint server 2001:503:c27::2:30 must respond to NS queries for the root zone.

 Warning    DNS: Root hint server 2001:7fd::1 must respond to NS queries for the root zone.

 Warning    DNS: Root hint server 2001:dc3::35 must respond to NS queries for the root zone.

 Warning    DNS: Root hint server 2001:500:2::c must respond to NS queries for the root zone.
```

I'm not sure where the BPA gets its list from... My cache.dns file has a correct up to date list.

Anyone has an idea what is going on :| ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so the answer turned out to be trivial...

There was an optional update pending to be installed that must have updated the BPA hint root list, because after I installed all pending optional updates, and reran the BPA, the warnings went away.